# ansible check variable is defined and has a value

Tags: ansible

I have many roles in our playbook that checks that any required variable(s) have been passed before they run to stop errors with missing values part way through a tasks

Playbook looks like this

```
role:
 - { role: ADMIN, Function: Function1 }
 - { role: ADMIN, Function: Function2 }
```

main.yml task file has an include for each Function

```
    include: "{{Function}}.yml"
```

the first task here is to include another task file checkVars.yml which has passed known required variables

Function1.yml

```
    include: checkVars.yml
    with_items: "{{REQUIRED_VARS}}"
    vars:
      REQUIRED_VARS:
        - param1
```

Function2.yml

```
    include: checkVars.yml
    with_items: "{{REQUIRED_VARS}}"
    vars:
      REQUIRED_VARS:
        - param2
```

checkVars.yml

```
- block:
   name: Check vars declared
      debug:
        msg: 
          - "##########################################################"
          - "# The variable '{{ item }}' is not defined or is empty"
          - "##########################################################"
      failed_when: var_failed 
      when: var_failed        
    rescue:
      - debug:
          msg: 
            - "{%if vars[item] is not defined %}{{item}} is Missing {%else%}{{item}} has no value{%endif%} "
      - meta: end_play
    vars:
      var_value:        "{%if vars[item] is defined %}{{vars[item]}}{%else%}{%endif%}"
      var_value_len:    "{{var_value|length}}"
      var_value_empty:  "{{var_value_len|int == 0}}"
      var_failed:       "vars[item] is not defined or var_value_empty"
```

running the playbook as it stands would error on the first role with

```
    "msg": [
            "##########################################################",
            "# The variable 'param1' is not defined or is empty",
            "##########################################################"
    "msg": [
            "param1 is Missing  "
        ]
```

This all words fine as the parameters passed defined in the group_vars by default, playbook or at command line..
knowing that for each group within the host files different values will be used for most values this is where in this case param1 and param2 are stored.
As part of some testing the playbook had variables added that did not have the same name as the  REQUIRED_VARS in the call and so the playbook was changed to show get this to work

```
    vars:
      paramb:
    role:
     - { role: ADMIN, Function: Function1, param1: {{paramb}}}
     - { role: ADMIN, Function: Function2 }
```

this now does not show that actually 'paramb' is empty as the checkVars.yml evaluates the param1 variable as '{{paramb}}' and not ''. Also the playbook does not fail if the paramb is not defined but waits for the check were it continues OK as the param1 is defined to the non existent variable
{{paramb}}

is there a way to make sure the ensure the param1 evaluates to the value of paramb and not just the string

The above was the Minimal, Reproducible Example to test this and ideally the added test line of...

```
    - { role: ADMIN, Function: Function1, param1: {{paramb}}}
```

would not occur in a real live environment, also the value of param1 required is actually a nested list of values, example

```
    vars
      cluster:
        receiver:
          - {name: RCVRName, ....}
        sender:
          - {name: SDRName, ....}
```

the functions can now be seen to provide tasks for the following

- Function1 is tasks on the receiver
- Function2 is tasks on the sender
  which now expands the checks further prior to running the tasks, first check is for the top level of 'cluster' in both tasks list, item found OK
  I now set in Function1 the addition variable to get the receiver details

```
     RCVR: "{{(cluster| default({})).reciever | default('')}}"
```

and add that to the REQUIRED_VARS list, output in checkVars.yml is

```
   "var_value           = {{(cluster| default({})).reciever | default('')}}",
   "var_value len       = 49"
```

however doing a debug after the call i see

```
    "RCVR = [{u'name': u'RCVR_NAME'}]"
```

not the same at all. I then commented out the sender part of the defined variables and the results were

```
       "var_value           = {{(cluster| default({})).sender | default('')}}",
       "var_value len       = 47",
       "SNDR = "
```

Comment: I suggest you double check and make sure you're not loosing time reinventing the wheel. The above looks overly complicated compared to the [already existing feature in ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-mandatory-values). That being said 1) your `checkVars.yml` file example is apparently missing a `block` definition (please [edit]) 2) checking the length of a defined but empty variable (even as imbricated reference) should theoretically do what you expect so you need to provide a [mre]. 2cent: try quotes arround `"{{ paramb }}"`

Comment: Zeitounator, thanks for the quick reply however there is more to the playbook than above, the above is a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
I have added extra details above

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/6a139e8f7cbbd0ba27ec47cb7cc8c57c). Please note that this link is a minimal reproducible example where you will find a file structure, file contents all with valid yaml, a complete playbook to test, the command actually used to launch it and the output result. Note as well I fixed some module names as `include` is deprecated (in favor of `include_X` where X is `tasks` in your case). And without much surprise (as reported in my above comment), this is working exactly as expected (i.e. I get an error for empty param).

Comment: Make the use case [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Make the testing consistent:

1. A variable is not defined.
2. A variable is defined. Depending on the type of value you can test the content, e.g.

- Fail if the value is *None (null)*
- Fail if the string is empty.
- Fail if the list is empty.
- Do nothing if the value is Boolean.
- Do nothing if the value is a dictionary.

```yaml
- block:
    - assert:
        that: lookup('varnames', item)|length > 0
        fail_msg: "{{ item }} is not defined."
        quiet: true
    - include_tasks: "check_{{ lookup('vars', item)|type_debug }}.yml"
  rescue:
    - set_fact:
        check_vars_error: true
    - meta: clear_host_errors
```

Instead of the filter *type_debug* you can use Jinja [tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests). A variable may pass more tests. For example, a string will pass tests iterable, sequence, and string.

```yaml
- block:
    - assert:
        that: lookup('varnames', item)|length > 0
        fail_msg: "{{ item }} is not defined."
        quiet: true
    - include_tasks: "check_{{ my_item }}.yml"
      loop: "{{ var_type|from_yaml|dict2items|json_query('[?value].key') }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: my_item
      vars:
        var_type: |
          {
          boolean: {{ lookup('vars', item) is boolean }},
          callable: {{ lookup('vars', item) is callable }},
          float: {{ lookup('vars', item) is float }},
          integer: {{ lookup('vars', item) is integer }},
          iterable: {{ lookup('vars', item) is iterable }},
          mapping: {{ lookup('vars', item) is mapping }},
          none: {{ lookup('vars', item) is none }},
          number: {{ lookup('vars', item) is number }},
          sequence: {{ lookup('vars', item) is sequence }},
          string: {{ lookup('vars', item) is string }}
          }
  rescue:
    - set_fact:
        check_vars_error: true
    - meta: clear_host_errors
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing using the filter *type_debug*

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── roles
    └── admin
        └── tasks
            ├── check_AnsibleUnsafeText.yml
            ├── check_bool.yml
            ├── check_dict.yml
            ├── check_list.yml
            ├── check_NoneType.yml
            ├── check_vars.yml
            ├── function_1.yml
            ├── function_2.yml
            └── main.yml
```

```bash
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
#   paramb:

  roles:
#   - {role: admin, function: function_1, param1: "{{ paramb }}"}
    - {role: admin, function: function_1}
    - {role: admin, function: function_2}
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/admin/tasks/main.yml 
- include_tasks: "{{ function }}.yml"
```

Fail if there was any error in testing the variables

```yaml
shell> cat roles/admin/tasks/function_1.yml 
- set_fact:
    check_vars_error: false
- include_tasks: check_vars.yml
  loop: "{{ required_vars }}"
  vars:
    required_vars:
      - param1
- fail:
    msg: Error testing required variables.
  when: check_vars_error
```

Report errors only and proceed

```yaml
shell> cat roles/admin/tasks/function_2.yml 
- include_tasks: check_vars.yml
  loop: "{{ required_vars }}"
  vars:
    required_vars:
      - param2
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/admin/tasks/check_vars.yml 
- block:
    - assert:
        that: lookup('varnames', item)|length > 0
        fail_msg: "{{ item }} is not defined."
        quiet: true
    - include_tasks: "check_{{ lookup('vars', item)|type_debug }}.yml"
  rescue:
    - set_fact:
        check_vars_error: true
    - meta: clear_host_errors
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/admin/tasks/check_AnsibleUnsafeText.yml 
- assert:
    that: lookup('vars', item)|length > 0
    fail_msg: "{{ item }} is empty string."
    quiet: true

shell> cat roles/admin/tasks/check_bool.yml 
- meta: noop

shell> cat roles/admin/tasks/check_dict.yml 
- meta: noop

shell> cat roles/admin/tasks/check_list.yml 
- assert:
    that: lookup('vars', item)|length > 0
    fail_msg: "{{ item }} is empty list."
    quiet: true

shell> cat roles/admin/tasks/check_NoneType.yml 
- fail:
    msg: "{{ item }} is None (null)."
```

1. A variable is not defined

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - {role: admin, function: function_1}
    - {role: admin, function: function_2}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: param1 is not defined.
  msg: Error testing required variables.
```

2. A variable is defined and has no value.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    paramb:
  roles:
    - {role: admin, function: function_1, param1: "{{ paramb }}"}
    - {role: admin, function: function_2}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: param1 is None (null).
  msg: Error testing required variables.
```

3. A variable is an empty string

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    paramb: ''
  roles:
    - {role: admin, function: function_1, param1: "{{ paramb }}"}
    - {role: admin, function: function_2}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: param1 is empty string.
  msg: Error testing required variables.
```

4. A variable is boolean

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    paramb: False
  roles:
    - {role: admin, function: function_1, param1: "{{ paramb }}"}
    - {role: admin, function: function_2}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: param2 is not defined.
```

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir, for the time you have taken here to provide the information, it all logically looks good but unfortunately i cannot use the suggestion. One thing i failed to submit was the version of ansible that we are using which 2.3 and a lot of the modules do not exist
I did start creating the example but found
loop new in 2.5
include_tasks new in 2.4
varnames lookup new in 2.8
there maybe more, we have no control over the version we can use so cannot upgrade

Comment: In this case, the main problem is missing lookup plugins *varnames* and *vars*. You cannot evaluate indirect addressing without the *vars* plugin. Depending on the particular use cases there might be workarounds using the filter *default*. Open a new [mre] question if you want to. You're welcome.